# Typescript and React: How to have typed refs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript with react. If I have a reference, for example

```
<SomeComponent ref="example-ref"></SomeComponent>
```

I can access it the usual way with `this.refs['example-ref']` and work from there. If I want it typed, I have to explicitly cast it:

```
var typedRef: SomeComponent = this.refs['example-ref'] as SomeComponent;
```

But how can I have typed references so that I don't have to cast them? Thanks

Comment: You might be able to do it by doing the casting within the [ref callback function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an alternative `ref`syntax works well for us i.e. declare a private var in the class

```
private comp: SomeComponent;
```

and then in the TSX

```
<SomeComponent ref={(c) => { this.comp = c } }/></SomeComponent>
```

Just access the typed `this.comp` in the rest of the code